# Script that provides the row counts and table names

Tags: sql, sql-server

Maybe you easily said how to I provide table names and row counts?

Pseudo SQL:

```
for "select tablename from system.Tables" into :tablename
  execute "select count(*) from ? into ?" using :tablename, :count
  return row(:tablename, :count)
end for
```

Can you tell me show me this script in T-SQL?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

If you're on SQL Server **2005 or newer** (you unfortunately didn't specify which **version** of SQL Server you're using), this query should give you that information:

```
SELECT 
    TableName = t.NAME,
    TableSchema = s.Name,
    RowCounts = p.rows
FROM 
    sys.tables t
INNER JOIN 
    sys.schemas s ON t.schema_id = s.schema_id
INNER JOIN      
    sys.indexes i ON t.OBJECT_ID = i.object_id
INNER JOIN 
    sys.partitions p ON i.object_id = p.OBJECT_ID AND i.index_id = p.index_id
WHERE 
    t.is_ms_shipped = 0
GROUP BY
    t.NAME, s.Name, p.Rows
ORDER BY 
    s.Name, t.Name
```

This produces an output something like (this is from `AdventureWorks`):

```
TableName       TableSchema      RowCounts
AWBuildVersion    dbo                  1
DatabaseLog       dbo               1597
ErrorLog          dbo                  0
Department        HumanResources      16
Employee          HumanResources     290
JobCandidate      HumanResources      13
Address           Person           19614
AddressType       Person               6
... and so on......
```

Comment: Arent't those rowcounts only estimates?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: not **estimates** - but approximations. The row counts are updated on a regular basis - but they're not 100% accurate at any given time if you did lots of inserts or deletes, that's correct. But doing a `SELECT COUNT(*)` across all tables in a decent size database with sizeable number of rows will just be **awful** in terms of performance and execution time....

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT 
t.NAME AS TableName, p.[Rows] FROM 
sys.tables t INNER JOIN
sys.partitions p ON t.object_id = p.OBJECT_ID GROUP BY 
t.NAME, p.[Rows] ORDER BY    t.NAME
```

Answer (score 1):

```
-- Shows all user tables and row counts for the current database 
-- Remove OBJECTPROPERTY function call to include system objects 
SELECT o.NAME,
  i.rowcnt 
FROM sysindexes AS i
  INNER JOIN sysobjects AS o ON i.id = o.id 
WHERE i.indid < 2  AND OBJECTPROPERTY(o.id, 'IsMSShipped') = 0
ORDER BY o.NAME
```

Comment: I will try all of the solutions! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
exec sp_MSForEachTable 'SELECT ''?'' as TableName, COUNT(*) as Rows FROM ?'
```

Answer (score 1):

I have adjusted the answer from marc_c with CTE and displaying it with choice of displaying just the schema you are after.

Should work with **SQL Serve 2005 and newer**.

```
WITH CountRowsInTables (Table_Name, Table_Schema, Row_Counts) AS
(
SELECT 
TableName = t.Name,
TableSchema = s.Name,
RowCounts = p.Rows
    FROM 
        sys.tables t
    INNER JOIN 
        sys.schemas s ON t.schema_id = s.schema_id
    INNER JOIN      
        sys.indexes i ON t.OBJECT_ID = i.object_id
    INNER JOIN 
        sys.partitions p ON i.object_id = p.OBJECT_ID AND i.index_id = p.index_id
    WHERE 
        t.is_ms_shipped = 0
    GROUP BY
        s.Name, t.Name, p.Rows
)

SELECT Table_name, Table_Schema, Row_Counts
    FROM CountRowsInTables
    WHERE Table_Schema = 'Pick_Schema_to_display';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
-- drop table #tmpspace
create table #tmpspace (
        name sysname
        , rows int
        , reserved varchar(50)
        , data varchar(50)
        , index_size varchar(50)
        , unused varchar(50)
        )

dbcc updateusage(0) with NO_INFOMSGS

exec sp_msforeachtable 'insert #tmpspace exec sp_spaceused ''?'''

select * from #tmpspace
order by convert(int, substring(reserved, 1, charindex(' ', reserved))) desc, rows desc, name
```

Works on sql2000 too.

`dbcc updateusage` might take some time but results will be 100% actual. Skip it if you need speed over accuracy.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
SELECT sc.name +'.'+ ta.name TableName
 ,SUM(pa.rows) RowCnt
 FROM sys.tables ta
 INNER JOIN sys.partitions pa
 ON pa.OBJECT_ID = ta.OBJECT_ID
 INNER JOIN sys.schemas sc
 ON ta.schema_id = sc.schema_id
 WHERE ta.is_ms_shipped = 0 AND pa.index_id IN (1,0)
 GROUP BY sc.name,ta.name
 ORDER BY SUM(pa.rows) DESC
```