# SAS Enterprise Guide - Export row counts for all tables

Tags: sql, sas

I am trying to create a data dictionary for a connection. I need to find out the size of each table. I can export a list of all tables and count the records for an individual table. Example of code:

```
proc sql;
connect to odbc as sql1 (dsn=EDWQA user=XXXX pw=XXXX readbuff=300 );

create table list4
as
select * from connection to sql1
(odbc::SQLTables);


create table list4
as
select * from connection to sql1
(select count(*) from ACCTLOAD.T_STG_IVR_LCIG_PLN1);

quit;
```

I will like to get an export of each table with the number of rows for each row. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi, Please add an example of the output you want; do you want to export to sas table or csv? what do you want your export to look like?

Comment: Tablename ;   Row Count

Answer (score 0):

Probably don't want to do this by `select count(*)` for every table in the data base -- your DBA might not appreciate it.  A much better query is to understand the host you are connecting to (not mentioned) and perform a metadata query on it directly.

```
proc sql;
  connect to odbc . . .;
  create table table_names_and_row_counts as
  from connection to obdc (
    select tablename, rowcount from
    *host DB meta query*
  );
```

The *host DB meta query* varies by db.  For SQL Server, see Stackoverflow [Script that provides the row counts and table names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9954775/script-that-provides-the-row-counts-and-table-names) answer that shows a query joining `sys.` tables `tables`, `schemas`, `indexes`, `partitions`

Comment: The host is a db2 database

Comment: If you have permissions and the most recent cataloged statistics are sufficient try using the `syscat.tables`, you can try this host query inside the `from connection to` -- `select tabname, card from syscat.tables where tabschema =
'<schemaName>'`